# What's the cream or powder that removes hair called?

Tags: word-request

I know there's a powder or cream that removes the hair (mainly from face) without any need to usage of blade. It's a chemical shaving.  Now, I thought it is called "shaving cream" or "shaving powder", but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaving_cream) these names refer to those powders or cream facilitate shaving so it's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the one that shaves without any further need to use blade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word you want is **depilatory**.  Here's a [defintion from M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/depilatory):

> : an agent for removing hair, wool, or bristles

And the [origin from Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/depilatory):

> c. 1600, "having the property of removing hair from the skin," from French *dépilatorie* (adj.), from Latin *depilatus* "having one's hair plucked," from *de-* "completely" (see de-) + *pilatus*, past participle of *pilare* "deprive of hair," from *pilus* "hair" (see pile (n.3)). Earlier in same sense was *Depilative*. As a noun, "application used to remove hair without injuring the skin," from c. 1600, from French *dépilatorie* (n.).

In addition, should you choose to enter this word in a search engine, you will discover many advertisements for creams, lotions, and so on which accomplish this task with varying degrees of reputibility.

Comment: +1. And the related verb is **depilate**.

Answer (score 10):

While, "depilatory" is the fancy, technical name for this, it's also often called just "hair removal cream". For instance, this site's headline: [The 5 Best Hair Removal Creams](https://www.wisebread.com/the-5-best-hair-removal-creams)

The powder form is also called "shaving powder", even though it's used *instead* of shaving. For instance, this product: [Magic Shaving Powder Red](https://www.pharmapacks.com/products.php?product=Magic-Shaving-Powder-Red-Extra-Strength-5-oz&gclid=CjwKCAiAsoviBRAoEiwATm8OYKcdVkYGGdYe1uKHLLWjPmYeUHZNNxiq5K7hWtr2VpdY0ie9Q10UGhoCRr8QAvD_BwE) ("Magic" is the brand name, not a suggestion that it works using supernatural means).

Answer (score 6):

In the US, the brand name ***Nair*** is sometimes used as a generic term for this (especially the cream, and especially by women). Compare "Kleenex" used for any facial tissue. A couple of examples, as a verb and a noun:

> [A different product] makes the hair grow back thinner softer and slower where i would need to nair before about once every 2 to 3 days pushing it at 3 i need to nair about once every 5 days with this. ([Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2LYWEXHWG1G41/) of other product)
>
> **Is nair/hair remover safe for repeated use?**
>   . . . . Right now I use the CVS generic for nair with aloe and lanolin, is that safe to use every couple weeks (over my full torso and arms/legs, obvs avoiding crotch and face)? ([Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/SkincareAddiction/comments/7q33sj/hair_removal_is_nairhair_remover_safe_for/))

Comment: 'Kleenex', Hoover', 'Nair' - eponyms.

Comment: Elsewhere (not sure about the geographic extent), _Veet_ is often used similarly.